# Compare two arrays and add new flag

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

I have two arrays, with same structure.

I have to compare them, and if item from second array is found in first array (by id) I should set flag **isNew** to **true** - otherwise to **false**.

```
const arr1 = [
    {
        id: 1,
        text: 'Text 1'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: 'Text 2'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: 'Text 3'
    }
];

const arr2 = [
    {
        id: 2,
        text: 'Text 2'
    }
];

const result = [
    {
        id: 1,
        text: 'Text 1',
        isNew: false
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: 'Text 2',
        isNew: true
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: 'Text 3',
        isNew: false
    }
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do this by combining `map` and `find`:

```
result = arr1.map(el => {
    if (arr2.find(el2 => el.id === el2.id) {
        el.isNew = true;
    }
    return el;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach:

```
const arr1Ids = [];

arr1.forEach((obj)=>{
  arr1Ids.push(obj.id);
});

arr2.forEach((obj)=>{
  if ( arr1IdArr.includes(obj.id) ) {
    result.forEach((rObj)=>{
      if ( rObj.id === obj.id ) {
        rObj.isNew = true;
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Although I upvoted GeorgeMA's answer because it is more concise